# Parameters in POST request changes automatically on the receiving end

Tags: java, eclipse, post, httpclient

I am using HTTPClient with Eclipse to generate a POST request to our own software.

Here is my POST request code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthenticationException;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicScheme;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

public class Posts {


    public void sendPost() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, AuthenticationException{


    HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/zarr-web/command/import/BDP?deltaImport=true");

    // Request parameters and other properties.
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fileName", "D:\\\\Colibri_workspace\\colibri_trunk\\zarr\\zarr-backend\\servers\\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\\bin\\presentation\\soap_automation\\BANKDIRECTORYPLUS_V3_DAILY_DELTA_20170930.txt"));

     UsernamePasswordCredentials creds
     = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("administrator", "administrator");

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
    httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    httppost.addHeader(new BasicScheme().authenticate(creds, httppost, null));

    //Execute and get the response.
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    if (entity != null) {
        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
        try {
            // do something useful
        } finally {
            instream.close();
        }
    }

    }
}
```

But when I send the request on the sending side the correct "filename" is sent however when the request is received on the other side the "filename" becomes:

> fileName=D%3A%5C%5CColibri_workspace%5Ccolibri_trunk%5Czarr%5Czarr-backend%5Cservers%5Cwildfly-8.2.0.Final%5Cbin%5Cpresentation%5Csoap_automation%5CBANKDIRECTORYPLUS_V3_DAILY_DELTA_20170930.txt

When I use SOAPUI software to send the request the file name is the same one as sent. Am I missing something here?

Please help.

Comment: encode filename using URLEncoder.encode(filename,"UTF-8") ;

Comment: This is why the file name is changing your characters are converting to something else here is a site for reference
https://www.obkb.com/dcljr/charstxt.html

Comment: @Satya it is not working. Can you please elaborate your solution (PS: Write it as an answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you did miss that body you send is URL Encoded. 
you did it explicitly:

`httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));`

and I bet because of `UrlEncodedFormEntity` actual "Content-Type" header is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

you can check what you actually send to the server by bringing up any kind of TCP monitor (as example Tcpmon). Then compare what your code sends and what SOAPUI does.

URL decoded value of your example is actually what you send:

```
fileName=D:\\Colibri_workspace\colibri_trunk\zarr\zarr-backend\servers\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\bin\presentation\soap_automation\BANKDIRECTORYPLUS_V3_DAILY_DELTA_20170930.txt
```

UPD:
First simple try make another than `UrlEncodedFormEntity`. As example `SringEntity`. If you have only one parameter just pass your file name parameter "as is":

like

```
"fileName=D:\\\\Colibri_workspace\\colibri_trunk\\zarr\\zarr-backend\\servers\\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\\bin\\presentation\\soap_automation\\BANKDIRECTORYPLUS_V3_DAILY_DELTA_20170930.txt"
```

if you have more parameters you need to separate them by `&` character, like:

{param1Name}={param1Value}&{param2Name}={param2Value} and so on.

But keep in mind if your value will have `&` in it all be broken.

I just can say that your server side software is not good. It needs form kind of body (param=value) but violates HTTP protocol...

Comment: Sorry for being a noob with this, before today I did not even know what POST request was. Can you please tell me exactly what I need to change in my code?

Comment: first simple try make another than `UrlEncodedFormEntity`. As example